# Django Database Issue (Related to upgrade from older version)

Tags: django

I recently upgraded Django to 1.6 after inheriting an old project that was using 1.1. Unfortunately this has broken a few things and I've having issues with one particular error that I can't seem to figure out:

> settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
>
> Request Method:   GET
>
> Request URL:
>
> Django Version:   1.6.5
>
> Exception Type:   ImproperlyConfigured
>
> Exception Value:   settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
>
> Exception Location:   /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py in complain, line 15
>
> Python Executable:    /usr/bin/python
>
> Python Version:   2.6.5

Here's the partial stacktrace:

> Traceback:
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in get_response
>   112. response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/var/django-dev/icp/icp_main/views.py" in temp
>   120. project = Project.objects.get(shortname=project_name)

It was previously using version 1.1 and I read that there were some changes, specifically in the settings.py location and specifiction. I moved the settings.py file into the inner folder and modified the DATABASES section:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': '/var/django-dev/icp/db.sqlite',
     }
}
```

From my understanding, it's not correctly setting the database. Also, I'm going to be redoing things completely as it was not well written and has all kinds of weird hacks and other oddities, but my concern is ensuring that the current version of the site is still available. Can anyone help me figure out why the database isn't being properly set or it's having some issue related to that?

It might be easier to just stop wasting time on the old version and start working on the new version.

Comment: Better start over by creating new django 1.6 project using `startproject`, then copy the relevant parts into appropriate places.

Comment: It will be quicker indeed to start a new project with Django 1.6 and then copy back app developed. You will still need to update these apps, but at least the project structure will be updated. (And there are a lot of changes between Django 1.1 to 1.6 in the settings, so... just start from scratch as I said)